# Handling an empty string - Python

Tags: python

I have to do a program for a Hexidecimal to Binary converter. I have it working fine. However the only thing that doesn't quite go to plan is if an empty string is entered. If invalid data is entered it produces an error, apart from when nothing is entered, where nothing is produced either. No error comes up, but it doesn't do anything either.

How would I make the error come up for an empty string?

```
def Binary(Hex):
    Result = ''
    ErrorFound = False
    BinaryEquivalent = ''
    for ThisHexDigit in Hex:
        if ThisHexDigit in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']:
            if ThisHexDigit == '0': BinaryEquivalent = '0'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '1': BinaryEquivalent = '1'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '2': BinaryEquivalent = '2'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '3': BinaryEquivalent = '3'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '4': BinaryEquivalent = '4'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '5': BinaryEquivalent = '5'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '6': BinaryEquivalent = '6'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '7': BinaryEquivalent = '7'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '8': BinaryEquivalent = '8'
            elif ThisHexDigit == '9': BinaryEquivalent = '9'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'A': BinaryEquivalent = '10'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'B': BinaryEquivalent = '11'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'C': BinaryEquivalent = '12'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'D': BinaryEquivalent = '13'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'E': BinaryEquivalent = '14'
            elif ThisHexDigit == 'F': BinaryEquivalent = '15'
            Result = Result + BinaryEquivalent
        else:
            ErrorFound = True
            print('You have made a mistake')
    return Result
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Please post the code.

Comment: Where does the input come from?  Please post some code.  It sounds like it's still waiting for input.

Comment: You might just want to throw an exception to catch the empty string.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, this is a remarkably bad method to do this operation.

Comment: Also, if "working fine" means that the binary equivalent of `0xFF` is `1515`, something's wrong with my math skills.

Comment: ErrorFound is doing nothing for you, and you shouldn't label things 'binary' when they are string representations of decimal values.  There are multiple functional issues with this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not hex_string:
    raise ValueError('Cannot convert empty string')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have often found myself asking if the String has any length to it

```
emptyInput = ""
if len(emptyInput): #returns 0 and will fail 
#but as the comments remind me
if emptyInput: #also returns false
```

now you have a few options from here. Simply adding an else and moving on, raising an error, or ask for new input. It really is hard to advise the best course without some of your code.

Comment: You can just use `if empty`. 0-length strings are Falsh-ish

Comment: this is true. Its been a few months since I really wrote anything in python.

Comment: also take out white-spaces before testing with the if statement like 
    empty = empty.strip()                          , so that if empty equals "  " it would still execute whats in the if statement

Comment: @bernabasd that is a fair suggestion, but that really depends on what input you are handling. This question asked to determine if string was empty, not that it needed to be preprocessed.

Comment: @matchew yap...your post answers the question 100%, just wanted to point out cases like len("  ") does not fail,